# Does the Datastore API for NodeJS use `distinct on` by default?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-distinct-on-query-nodejs

When reading the documentation about querying entities, I noticed that keys-only queries and projection queries without a `distinct on` clause are considered small operations, which according to their quota and pricing are considered free.

However, when you look at the examples from different languages on that page, it looks like several (C#, Java, PHP, etc...) support a way of telling the query to specifically perform a `distinct on` operation, but there doesn't seem to be support in NodeJS for specifying this directly. This seems to significantly impact cost, but NodeJS is missing support.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the NodeJS API use distinct by default, though you should be able to do a simple test to confirm. Looking through the [examples](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#grouping) tells me that NodeJS API uses a slightly different terminology, and calls it `groupBy` for fetching distinct results. Here is the link to the [API Documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.0.0/datastore/query?method=groupBy).